# Versiones - ¿Como puedo saber la version de mi aplicacion mediante codigo?

Tags: android

como puedo obtener este dato del gradle: versionName "1.0.2"
Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

También si está utilizando el complemento Gradle/Android Studio, a partir de la [versión 0.7.0](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system), el código de versión y el nombre de la versión están disponibles estáticamente en `BuildConfig`. Asegúrese de importar el paquete de su aplicación , y no otra `BuildConfig`:

```
import com.yourpackage.BuildConfig;
...
int versionCode = BuildConfig.VERSION_CODE;
String versionName = BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME;
```

¡No se necesita un objeto de contexto!

También asegúrese de especificarlos en su archivo `build.gradle` en lugar de `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
defaultConfig {
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0.2"
}
```

> Fuente So: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21119027/8933039

---

Adicional a la respuesta proporcionada por @Einer, si desea obtener también el código de la versión de la aplicación (mayor, menor y parche) en tiempo de ejecución.

Puede ver los principios de [control de versiones semánticas](https://semver.org/).

Obtener el `versionName`:

```
packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    .versionName; // throws NameNotFoundException
```

Parse the `versionName`:

```
// check versionName against ^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
final String[] versionNames = versionName.split("\\.");
final Integer mayor = Integer.valueOf(versionNames[0]);
final Integer menor = Integer.valueOf(versionNames[1]);
final Integer patch = Integer.valueOf(versionNames[2]);
```

ASEGÚRESE de manejar todos los errores posibles.

Answer (score 7):

Utilizando el `PackgeManager` del context puedes obtener la version de tu aplicacion:

```
public String obtenerVersionApp() 
{
    try {
        PackageInfo paquete = this.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
        String versionDeAplicacion = paquete.versionName;

      return versionDeAplicacion;

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  return null;
}
```